# Adding claims to already logged in user with Bearer token authentication

Tags: .net-6.0, claims-based-identity

I have a .Net 6 application. I would like to persist some data to the user session and thought claims is probably an easy way to do it.

As far as I can understand this is the correct way to add claims to the user after the initial login.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
   new Claim("claimType", "blabla")
};
context.User.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
```

If I check the `Identities` before that request ends there is a new record added which contains the claim I created. But upon the next request to the server it is gone. Only the original Identity is there again.

[image]

The value I want to add is calculated during runtime and can't be created during login. I could add it to the database but I REALLY don't want to as I need to check it on every request.

What might I be doing wrong? Or any suggestions to alternate ways to store the information?

Update 1:
Because it might matter, we use an external identity provider and token based authentication to a .net 6 api.